# Server error "could not load type application.global" on new .net application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

this one is making me crazy, i have a windows 10 machine with vs studio 2017 and iss Express, when i make a new .net web application project (.net framework) and run it  without modifying anything at all i get this on the browser:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details 
and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication2.Global'.
Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"  Inherits="WebApplication2.Global" Language="C#" %>
Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

Version Information: 
Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; 
ASP.NET Version:4.7.3160.0
```

it doesnt matter what type of project i start.

already try cleaning and rebuilding, setting the build folder to bin/ and bin/debug, and changing "Codebehind" by CodeFile" on the .asax file  but it is always the same, i believe there is something i need to configure or install but for the live of me i cant figure it out.

questions:

1.***whats the cause to this error?***

2.***what do i need to have install to run .net web applications locally?***`

`

Answer (score 0):

please try downgrading your project version to 4.0 and try to run it.You have a .NET Version Conflict.Since your ASP.NET Version is 4.7 some CLI Commands might not work if you have a less .NET version.